# Check whether a given quantity is negative

Tags: mathematical-optimization, algebraic-manipulation

Given four numbers $n0, n1, n2, n4$ such that $n1+n2+n3+n4 = 1$. How can we check the sign of $A - 2 B$ (where $A$ and $B$ are defined below), i.e., whether this quantity is positive or negative?

```
A = (n0 + n1 - n2 - n3)^2;
B = (n0 - n1)^2 + (n2 - n3)^2;

Expand[A - 2 B]

Out[21]= -n0^2 + 6 n0 n1 - n1^2 - 2 n0 n2 - 2 n1 n2 - n2^2 - 
 2 n0 n3 - 2 n1 n3 + 6 n2 n3 - n3^2
```

Comment: `Reduce[A - 2 B < 0 && n0 + n1 + n2 + n3 == 1]`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sgn[n0_?NumericQ, n1_?NumericQ, n2_?NumericQ, n3_?NumericQ] := Module[{A = (n0 + n1 - n2 - n3)^2,B = (n0 - n1)^2 + (n2 - n3)^2},Sign[A - 2 B]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make visualization to roughly understand what values of `n0, n1,n2, n3` correspond to `A-2 B` being positive or negative.

```
A = (n0 + n1 - n2 - n3)^2;
B = (n0 - n1)^2 + (n2 - n3)^2;

Simplify[A - 2 B, n0 + n1 + n2 + n3 == 1]

(* -1 - 8 n1^2 + 8 n2 n3 - 8 n1 (-1 + n2 + n3) *)

RegionPlot3D[-1 - 8 n1^2 + 8 n2 n3 - 8 n1 (-1 + n2 + n3) > 0,
{n1, -10, 10}, {n2, -10, 10}, {n3, -10, 10}, 
AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, BaseStyle -> 12]
```

[image]

Empty space in picture represent region where `A-2 B < 0`.